# AnimatedVectorDrawable not showing any animations API 21+

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am following android guideline to use animated vector drawable [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html).

I have made xml vector file using android vector studio **(img_logo.xml)**

Animated vector drawable xml file

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo" >
    <target
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:animation="@anim/rotate" />
    <target
        android:name="v"
        android:animation="@anim/anim_path" />
</animated-vector>
```

and set this to imageview

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/view_elevation"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
```

I also tried animating from code using below code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480074/animatedvectordrawable-does-not-animate)

```
AnimatedVectorDrawable d = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.anim_logo); // Insert your AnimatedVectorDrawable resource identifier
mImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
d.start();
```

Belom are animation xml
**anim_path.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0   -70,70z"
        android:valueTo="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,0  0,140 -70,0 z"
        android:valueType="pathType" />
</set>
```

**rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="360" />
</set>
```

you can find vector drawable from [here](http://textuploader.com/ddtdd)

I have set everything up as mentioned in guide but when I run the app it is not animating the Image. any help Appreciated.

Comment: Don't think there's enough info here to answer. What is the xml of your VectorDrawable and Animators? What do you see on screen? any error messages?

Comment: @LewisMcGeary please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the VectorDrawable is quite large and complex. This shouldn't stop it working, but may lead to poor performance; for reference, the documents recommend [200dp x 200dp as the maximum size](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#about).

The reason that this isn't a working animation though, is that the AnimatedVectorDrawable is trying to target parts of the VectorDrawable which don't exist.
In the lines:

```
    <target
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:animation="@anim/rotate" />
    <target
        android:name="v"
        android:animation="@anim/anim_path" />
```

The target names specify which part of the VectorDrawable to apply each animation to, so somewhere in the VectorDrawable we would expect to find them:

```
    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        ...

    <path
        android:name="v"
        ...
```

But there are no parts of the VectorDrawable with names that match the intended targets, so to make a working animation you would need to fix that.